# Given the function $f(x)=(1+x)^n$ Show that $L(x)=1$+nx is the linearization of $f$ at $0$ ...

Tags: calculus

So this is how the question goes.
1. Given the function $f(x)=(1+x)^n$.$$$$
    a. Show that $L(x)=1$+nx is the linearization of $f$ at $0$.$$$$
    b. A friend claims that the cube root of 1.1 is about 1.03. Without using a calculator, do you think the $$$$

c. Without using a calculator do you think $(1.1)^\frac{1}{3}$ is larger or smaller than 1.03? Explain. (Hint graphing may help)

So for a I did$$L(x)=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$$ $$a= 0$$
$$f(a)=(1+0)^n=1$$
$$f'(x) = n(1+x)^{n-1}$$
$$f'(a)=n(1+0)^{n-1}=n$$
so $$L(x)=n(x-0)+1=1+nx$$
So for b I used $(1+.1)^\frac{1}{3}$ and plugged into $L(x)$ and got $1.033...$. But I have no Idea on how to go about solving c. Do I just use my answer from b and say that's why? I think there's an specific process towards solving that precisely but I'm not sure how. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: solve an equation. and find out for what values of $x$; $(1+.1)^\frac{1}{x}$ is larger , smaller or equal to $1.03$. that will tell you about $(1+.1)^\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: An other idea would be to look at the sign of the remaining terms that you remove when you do the linerarization. You can explicitely do the math for n=2, n=3 and recursively prove that for every n, the results holds.

Comment: Hiko Seijuro didn't teach you this?